# Continuous current capacity of this conductor?

Tags: current, resistance, cables, maximum-ratings

How much current can a copper conductor that is 2 meters long, 0.003m thick, and 0.00045m wide continuously carry? Also, the resistance is about 0.02 Ohms.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ampacity+calculator

Comment: You might want to consider temperature as well...

Comment: It also depends on environment. In vacuum it will be lower than on diamond heatsink.

Comment: @venny Diamond heatsink sounds very expensive.

Comment: @JYelton so does in a vacuum

Comment: How much voltage drop and/or temperature rise can you tolerate?

Comment: Can that conductor transfer continuous power(190W)(DC source) at temperature = 60C?  9A at 21V?

Comment: If the current were AC at 50MHz it's resistance would be significantly larger and it's current carrying capability much diminished.

Comment: @Andyaka It's DC, so at max how much power could it continuously deliver? Is 29V x 9A possible? Without fusing? I edited the voltage, should be 29V not 21V.

Comment: +1 This was my test question to see if I should join this site. Great question and good comments, plus I cannot immediately see the answer.

Comment: @DaveTweed Voltage drop would be at most 2V, and temperature at most 60C, DC current. The goal is to deliver 261W continuously without fusing.

Comment: The definitive answer would require finite element analysis. But comparing current density (here it is \$6.7\,\mathrm{A/mm^2}\$, cables for house wiring are about \$6.4\,\mathrm{A/mm^2}\$ with thick PVC sheath), it seems that it will probably work fine without much heating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your conductor is flat, its cross-sectional area is 1.35mm. The resistivity of pure copper at 20°c is 1.72*10<sup>-8</sup> Ohms/m. Resistance = resistivity x length / area, so your 2m length should measure about 0.026 Ohms.

The equivalent circular wire diameter is 1.31mm, which is slightly larger than 16AWG ( typically rated at 20A in a single core cable). At 9A it will drop about 0.23V and dissipate about 2W over its entire length.

Comment: So what is the conclusion? Is 2W little or a lot? How hot will the wire get?

Comment: 2W spread over a 2m length of wire? That's 10mW per cm. If it was a PCB trace then the temperature rise would be about 0.5°c. You would need a sensitive thermometer to measure it.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I assumed that the area is what I should've focused on to compare it to a round wire, because I know a conductor like that should easily manage 9A, and it seems it can and more, so 300W is not an issue for this conductor, 30Vx10A?

Comment: Yes, or 600W = 60V at 10A etc. Only the current matters. Maximum voltage is determined by the insulation.